# using java 8 groupBy with conditions

Tags: java

1. Group by number to find groups with size bigger then 1
       2. Check if a group contains a condition (string !=null)

   ```
   2a. if yes ---> remove all rows which do not have a condition (string == null)
   2b. if no ---> return the group as it is (no filtering at all)
   ```

I am trying below code but I am not able to filter the condition here. Is there any simple way to do it?

```
groupByList = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(student::no));
groupByList.values().stream().map(group -> group.size() > 1)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Shouldn't the student `no` be unique and `groupingBy` is a `Map` not a `List`.

Comment: Have you used `filter` instead of `map`? But be aware that all groups in `groupByList` have at least element, otherwise they wouldn't exist.

Comment: if i am using filter. i won't get list of single records. only i want compare greater than 1 size list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use both Stream.filter(..) and Stream.map(..)

```
// Groups students by group number
Map<String, List<Student>> allGroups = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(student::no));
// Filters groups that have more than 1 member
Map<String, List<Student>> filteredGroups = allGroups.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue().size() > 1).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
// Removes all non-null members
Map<String, List<Student>> cleanGroups = filteredGroups.entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> {
        entry.setValue(entry.getValue().stream().filter(student -> student.name != null).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return entry;
    }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

You can pipe the execution into one big chain:

```
Map<String, List<Student>> cleanGroups = list.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(student::no))
      .entrySet().stream()
      .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().size() > 1)
      .map(entry -> {
         entry.setValue(entry.getValue().stream()
                             .filter(student -> student.name != null)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return entry;
      })
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Please note, that you have a hidden object transformation withing the .filter(..).collect(..) above. If you need to skip that (at cost of double comparison), you can extend the lambda method to:

```
 .map(entry -> {
     if (entry.getValue().stream.anyMatch(student.name == null)) {
        entry.setValue(entry.getValue().stream().filter(student -> student.name != null).collect(Collectors.toList()));
     }
     return entry;
 })
```

Comment: I checked this code. here i am facing one problem don't need to remove entry.getValue().size() < 1 record . i need this record also.

Comment: Just remove the .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().size() > 1)  line then. Rest of code is the same. I've wrote an answer that matches the problem as per my understanding "Group by number to find groups with size bigger then 1".